# What is the meaning of "a little cushion" and "at yard sales"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Yes, money is our madness. Last year, we thought we had found ***a
>   little cushion*** when I published a book about the life here in suburban
>   America. It sold 12 copies——six of them to my mother. Four other
>   copies went to various aunts and uncles, who used them for martini
>   coasters (杯垫), then sold them ***at yard sales***. The two remaining copies
>   went to perfect strangers. (I think I owe you dinner, whoever you are.
>   Call me, OK? We’ll arrange something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might already know, a cushion is some sort of pillow. In a financial context, it has the meaning of *having some extra money*, so any sudden expenses wouldn't hit as hard. They "cushion the blow".

At a yard sale, people just set up shop in their own yard to sell used items, not unlike a small flea market.
Another word for that would be *garage sale*.